# Alternative to calculating Elasticity using For Loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I've written a piece of code to calculate elasticity for some 200k products. Elasticity is being calculated alright but it's been more than 15 hours and the process is still running. I see new objects being created. Is there a faster alternative to doing this without using a for loop?

Below is my code:

```
    sku_list <- unique(transact_data4$productId)
    elasticity_values <- data.frame()

    for (i in 1:length(sku_list)){
     test_sku <- subset(transact_data4, productId==sku_list[i])
     m1 <- lm(formula=sales~price, data= test_sku)
     coeffs <- as.data.frame(m1[[1]])
     gradient<- coeffs[2,1]
     gradient_final <- ifelse(is.na(gradient), -1, gradient)
     mean_price <- mean(test_sku$price)
     mean_sales <- mean(test_sku$sales)
     elasticity <- gradient_final*mean_price/mean_sales
     sku_elasticity <- cbind(sku_list[i],elasticity)
     elasticity_values <- rbind(elasticity_values,sku_elasticity)
    }
colnames(elasticity_values)[colnames(elasticity_values)=="V1"] <- "productId"
```

Here are is a sample dataset:

```
transact_data <- data.frame(productId=c('A', 'A','A', 'A','A', 'A','B', 'B','B', 'B','B', 'B'),
                  price=c(10, 10.5, 11, 12,10, 9,
                    10, 11, 13, 11,12.5, 11),
                    sales =c(100,93,90,85,99,110,101,95,80,103,82,102), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Result:

```
  productId         elasticity
1         A -0.913344887348354
2         B  -1.03051724343462
```

Is there a faster way to achieve this without using a for loop?
Obviously due to the smaller sample (only 2 productId) this runs fast.
But i'm trying to run this for over 200k productId.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)

transact_data %>% group_by(productId) %>%
   do(mod = lm(sales ~ price, data = .), 
      mean.price = mean(.$price), 
      mean.sales = mean(.$sales)) %>%
   summarise(productId  = productId,
             elasticity = ifelse(is.na(coef(mod)[2]), -1, coef(mod)[2]) * 
                          mean.price / mean.sales)

#   productId elasticity
# 1         A -0.9133449
# 2         B -1.0305172
```

**Explanation**

With `library(dplyr)` you can conveniently do this grouped calculations:

- `%>%` is the chaining operator, which makes the code more readable by inputting the left argument as the first argument to the function on the right
- `group_by` tells the next commands that you want to group by column `productId`
- `do` is used to calculate the model and the needed mean values, within `do` you use the dot `.` to refer to the whole `data.frame`
- `summarise` finally summarises your calculation, by computing the elasticity

For further info check `vignette("introduction")`.

It is by the way no big surprise that your code is quite slow, as you you use loops and on top of it increment your data in the loop.  Check http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf for some tutorial on common pitfalls.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thanks for providing the explanation as well.

Comment: Just had to add that this method is simply brilliant! It actually shows the percentage completion. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Just out of curiosity, how long did the calculation finally last? Tried here a sample dataset with `1e7` rows and 10000 distinct product IDs and it only took about a minute. So what was you time?

Comment: For Loop - over 15 hours that I had to kill. Using Pipes and Do - 22 minutes. Fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can optimize your code

1)The function apply, sapply,... are way faster than a for loop

2)rbind and cbind are slow if you work with big data. I suggest you to create your big data.frame (empty) with already the good number of columns and rows and then populate it.

Have fun!